# Input button not working using Bootstrap

Tags: php, button, input, twitter-bootstrap-3, contact-form

I have been using Bootstrap 3 to develop a project im working on and so far it has worked wonders and cant really fault it. However I have now run into a problem that I cant seem to get my head around.

**Problem:** A basic input submit button not doing anything - but when run on its own page i.e. without bootstrap it runs fine.

Here is the code:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <?php
                // define variables and set to empty values
                $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

                if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                   $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
                   $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
                   $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
                }

                function test_input($data) {
                   $data = trim($data);
                   $data = stripslashes($data);
                   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                   return $data;
                }
                ?>

                <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                   Name: <input type="text" name="name">
                   <br><br>
                   E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
                   <br><br>
                   Comment: <br>
                    <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
                   <br><br>
                   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>

                <?php
                echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
                echo $name;
                echo "<br>";
                echo $email;
                echo "<br>";
                echo $comment;
            ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

If you need to have a look at it running on a page with other content you can do so [here](http://rgriffiths-designs.co.uk/Kamology/contactus.php)

Also I am planning to get this working as a contact form, but no matter what PHP code I put I still get this problem.

Comment: `echo $message;` not `echo $comment;` - your form worked fine, besides not echoing the message I typed.

Comment: I get these errors in console:
TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined agency.js:12:23
TypeError: firstName is undefined contact_me.js:17:0

Comment: @TimLewis I'm not sure if it is just your connection or if he's fixed the errors but the site loaded instantly for me.

Comment: Huh. Probably my connection then. Seems to be fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this code in your contact_me.js that's causing the issue:

```
8.   submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
9.     event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
10.    // get values from FORM
11.    var name = $("input#name").val();
...
15.    var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
16.    // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
17.    if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
18.      firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
...
```

Console returns the error:

```
TypeError: firstName is undefined
```

I think you're selecting the name improperly. Try using:

```
var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest you do is in your form leave get **rid of the action=""** then in the PHP code before all the variable cleansing and displaying takes place add the following code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Clean input, validate input. Then below output the form data.
}
```

Basically what this code does it checks if the submit form is pressed and as the form is specified to be a POST it checks. It will only clean and display if the the submit button is pressed. Try that and tell me how it goes. You might be confused why I put submit in the POST, it is because your submit button has got a name="submit", so you use that name. If you changed it to name="contactUs" then you'd do *isset($_POST['contactUs'])*.

**EDIT:**

I wrote a simple example and it works when executed, you'll need to adapt it to fit your code.

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">

            <?php
                function test_input($data) {
                   $data = trim($data);
                   $data = stripslashes($data);
                   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                   return $data;
                }
            ?>

            <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
            <form method="post">
               Name: <input type="text" name="name">
               <br><br>
               E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
               <br><br>
               Comment: <br>
                <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
               <br><br>
               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
                $email = test_input($_POST['email']);
                $comment = test_input($_POST['message']);

                echo $name . " - " . $email . " - " . $comment . " - ";
            }
            ?>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```